# How to interchange index of multiple array in javascript and create a new array

Tags: arrays, node.js

Following is my input data

```
{ menu_name: 'testmenu',
 table_name: 'test_tbl',
 field_name: [ 'booktitle', 'bookid', 'bookauthor' ],
 field_type: [ 'varchar', 'int', 'varchar' ],
 field_size: [ '55', '11', '100' ] }
```

How can i convert this data to following array format

```
['testmenu','test_tbl','booktitle','varchar','55']
['testmenu','test_tbl', 'bookid','int','11']
['testmenu','test_tbl','bookauthor','varchar','100']
```

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this with the help of Array map method,

```js
let obj = {
    menu_name: 'testmenu',
    table_name: 'test_tbl',
    field_name: ['booktitle', 'bookid', 'bookauthor'],
    field_type: ['varchar', 'int', 'varchar'],
    field_size: ['55', '11', '100']
}

let result = obj.field_name.map((x, i) => [obj.menu_name, obj.table_name, x, obj.field_type[i], obj.field_size[i]]);
console.log(result);
```